# Count of 2 and 5 in double factorial

Tags: algorithm, math, factorial

How we can find a count of `2` and `5` in *double factorial* (`n!!`)? I mean *factorization*. For factorial `n!` we have an algorithm called *Super-Algorithm*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about practical computer programming but rather belongs on [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) once the questioner has added more of his own work and explained just where he is stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have a *Super Algorithm* which returns number of `2` and `5` for `n!` let's put it as `sa(n, 2)` and `sa(n, 5)`; for *double factorial* we have **2** cases

**Even** number, `2n`:

```
  (2n)!! = 2**n * n!
```

So number of `2`s is

```
   n + sa(n, 2)
```

and number of `5`s is

```
   sa(n, 5)
```

**Odd** number, `2n + 1`:

```
   (2n + 1)!! = (2n + 1)! / (2n)!!
```

So we have for number of `2`s:

```
   sa(2n + 1, 2) - (n + sa(n, 2)) = sa(2n + 1, 2) - sa(n, 2) - n
```

for number of `5`s

```
   sa(2n + 1, 5) - (sa(n, 5)) = sa(2n + 1, 5) - sa(n, 5)
```

Finally, let's put it as pseudocode `dfsa` (double factorial super algorithm), `n % 2` means remainder, `n / 2` - integer division:

```
   dfsa2(n) => n % 2 == 0 
      ? n / 2 + sa(n / 2, 2)
      : sa(n, 2) - sa(n / 2, 2) - n / 2;

   dfsa5(n) => n % 2 == 0 
      ? sa(n / 2, 5)
      : sa(n, 5) - sa(n / 2, 5);
```